# All files and folders on my Macbook Air now have year 2018 in their timestamp

Tags: mac, finder, timestamp

Somewhere last year, all files and folders on my Mac suddenly started displaying "2018" as their creation and modification year. This happened in Finder but also in the photo app Picasa. Day and month were still displayed correctly, and Get Info in Finder revealed the true dates. Also, sorting by date in Finder yielded the correct sort order. This problem initiated under OS X El Capitan but it persists now that I upgraded to Mac OS Mojave. Photos.app does display the correct dates. How can I get Finder to display the true creation and modification years of files and folders? Thanks, everyone!

Answer (score 1):

The question was answered in Apple Communities by Malcolm J. Rayfield. Turns out I had accidentally typed in a fixed year in 
System Preferences > Language and Region > Advanced > Dates.
 If you have a similar problem, go there and look for a year printed in black on a white background. Delete that and replace it by dragging in the black-on-blue year variable from Date Elements, lower left corner (on my Mac Mojave it shows 1976 in black on blue).

Comment: Care to provide that link?